# Prussian Jews and tallit gadol

Tags: minhag, marriage, tallit-gadol, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, yekke

The custom of Jews from Prussia (German Poland) was wear tallit gadol from bar mitzvah or from marriage? And the custom of Ashkenazi Jews from Belgium?

Comment: The famed Rabbi Akiva Eiger was in Posen, though honestly I don't recall hearing anything about his customs per se. They say he did generally follow the halachic guidance of Rabbi Moshe Issreles, who was from Krakow ... that's one very, very small data point indicating "from marriage", though I don't know much on the subject. When you say "Ashkenazim from Belgium" -- my impression is that the original ones were gone by the late 1300s, and those who were there in the past few centuries came from Eastern Europe, with their customs. So my gut would say "marriage" on both these categories.

Comment: @Shalom The Ashkenazi Jews that were gone from Belgium about 1370. From 1370 to 1492 and from 1556 to 1648, Belgium was without Jews. From 1492 to 1556 and from 1648 to 1920, practically all of Jews in Belgium was Western Sephardic. In 1920s Belgium was received German and Austrian Jews (who uses tallit gadol from bar mitzvah), but in 1930s Belgium was received Polish and Romanian Jews (who uses tallit gadol from marriage), and the Belgian Jews was formed a melting pot of minhagim until the Holocaust.

Comment: Then I think that's your answer right there: there was no single minhag.